# exit() syscall within shellcode not working

Tags: assembly, shellcode

```
int main()
{
    char shellcode[] = "\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80";

    int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

I tried to run the above shellcode but got a segmentation fault.
Then, I tried putting the shellcode inside the main and it worked, why?

Also, when I do `strace` to the binary to check the syscall, it shows that `exit_group()` syscall is called but the shell code is for `exit()` syscall.

[image: screenshot of strace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the opcodes that you are pointing are not responsible for the syscall. If you disassemble your shellcode, you get:

```
0000000000004028 <shellcode>:
    4028:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
    402d:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    4032:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

A first `mov` to set `ebx` to zero (the return code), then a second `mov` to set `eax` to the id of the `exit` syscall, and finally it trigger the system call.

Second, this shellcode is obviously designed for a 32-bit architecture. And, you have to know that the syscall numbers are different between i386 and amd64.

So, my recommendation would be that you compile your program with the option `-m32` to ensure that you have a full 32-bit program (and not a mix between 64-bit and 32-bit).

Third, you need to be sure that you compile with `-zexecstack` in order to be able to execute the code in case it is stored on the stack.

Finally, there is no evidence that getting `ret + 2` will set your pointer in front of the saved `eip`. You'd better write:

```
int main()
{
    char shellcode[] = "\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80";

    (*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using i386 machine. I believe the `0x1` which is being set to `eax` is responsible for `exit` syscall. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I tried again compiling the program with `-m32` option and got exactly the same disassemble as you have mentioned. But, the issue still remains the same. I am using now `char shellcode[] = "\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80";`

Comment: Ah, in fact, the `exit()` syscall call the `exit_group()` function to kill all threads. So, it might be okay from the beginning. Look at `man exit_group`

Comment: I think the program is crashing because whatever the opcode number instead of `0x1` I pass, I am getting the same result and hence the `exit_group()` is called rather than `exit()`

Comment: Are you compiling with `-zexecstack` ?

Comment: Tried with this option as well. Same result.

Comment: Try with function pointer, it will work (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Also, my initial shellcode program in the question where I was getting the Segmentation Fault also worked when I put the shellcode array outside the main and compiled with `-zexecstack` option. Could you please help me to understand how does it make difference keeping the `shellcode array` inside or outside the main. And how does `(*(void(*)()) shellcode)();` works?

Comment: Mainly the position of the `shellcode` variable will be somewhere else in memory if you write it inside a function (then, it will be stored on the stack) or outside (then, it will be stored in the `.data` section). And, the function pointer is just here to move `eip` to the shellcode. In your original code, you were rewriting the saved `eip` on the stack. You should read [this article](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html) in depth. It explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
div eax
int 0x80
jmp short 0x0
```

It's different ways `exit()` syscall